# Do Angular Reactive Form Validator.min/max check Perform Type Conversions before checking the value?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

### Preface:

Part of the reason why I'm asking the below questions is that when I do `form.value.purchaseCost` without having `type=number` on the `<input>` field, I get a string.  I had to do a manual conversion from to `Number` in order to check the field manually.  Initially I assumed that Angular would store the value as a number on the form since it has a `Validators.min` constraint on it.

### Question

This is the field definition:

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput type="number" formControlName="purchaseCost" placeholder="Purchase cost*">
    <mat-error>Please enter a purchase cost</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
```

And this is the Validator check:

```
purchaseCost: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.min(0)]),
```

Since the form field is of `type="number"` does the `FormControl` perform a conversion before it checks that the entry in the field is greater than 0 (min(0))?

Also if we get the `form.value.purchaseCost` do we need to convert `purchaseCost` to a number before using it or does the Angular Reactive Forms implementation do this for us since the field `type=number`?

In other words Angular Reactive Forms will store the value as the type contained on the `<input>` field?

Comment: Yes it will do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will internally perform type conversion while carrying out the validations based on the rules you have set on the form control.

Therefore, you may choose to remove the `type` attribute on your input. If you were to remove it, I would recommend you to include another Validator on your form control such that it checks if the input is a number.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [formControl]="purchaseCost" placeholder="Purchase cost*">
  <mat-error *ngIf="purchaseCost.errors && purchaseCost.errors.required">Please enter a purchase cost</mat-error>
  <mat-error *ngIf="purchaseCost.errors && purchaseCost.errors.min">Min. value is 0</mat-error>
  <mat-error *ngIf="purchaseCost.errors && purchaseCost.errors.pattern">Please enter a number</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

And on your component.ts, I added a regex [pattern validator](https://angular.io/api/forms/PatternValidator) on the `purchaseCost` form control.

```
purchaseCost = new FormControl('', [
  Validators.required, 
  Validators.pattern("^[0-9]*$"), 
  Validators.min(0)
]);
```

I have a added a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/example-angular-material-reactive-form-dnobpx?file=app/app.component.ts) over here.

Comment: you can use the "safe" operator '*ngIf="purchaseCost.errors?.required"`

Comment: @Eliseo ah, yes, you could!! I keep forgetting about the safe navigation operator :) Thank you!!